# Opening the keyboard after connecting to the server and recalling the contents of FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a registration form and after completing it I send a request to the server and if it is successful I show the dialog to the user but after closing the dialog the keyboard opens again and the same dialog is called 3 times

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in the `TextField` properties, add this:

```
autofocus: false,
```

Comment: I'm sorry , not working